# Simple: how to make the test for a false case?

Tags: prolog

The test should returns true: if the first part is true, and the second part is false.

Tried to do something like that:

```
f_test  :- f(x), % 1st part
           f(y) is false. % 2nd part
```

But it gives me an error:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `false/0' is not a function.
```

Please tell me, how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(is)/2` is a predicate intended to perform arithmetic. Even if your test was about arithmetic, the use of `(=:=)/2` would be preferred (because `(is)/2` is used to instantiate a variable. When you use it to check a variable value, you misuse it. OTOH, `(=:=)/2` is used to compare numbers).

But here your test isn't about arithmetic, it's about knowing if something is true or not. There is an operator for that, which checks if a given term is provable or not, it's `(\+)/1`, use is:

```
f_test :-
    f(x),
    \+ f(y).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
f_test :- f(x), \+f(y).
```